# LDAP authentication on MQ qmgr

Tags: ldap, mq

I wanted to know if there is any option to enable LDAP authentication for any particular channel .
i have configured the LDAP authentication on the Qmgr ,so every application connecting to the qmgr needs to provide the LDAP credentials to authenticate.Instead i want only the admins to use the LDAP authentication not the applications.

Is there a way to obtain this

Answer (score 0):

A way around this is to let your applications connect to the queuemanager using certificates (not credentials) and configure the application (SVRCONN) channels to use the certificates to authenticate the application.
The admin users has to use LDAP credentials to connect to the queuemanager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,currently the applications are not configured to use certificates.just checking if there is  any other way to restrict the authentication for only mqm user

Comment: I have found this in google which says if the CHCKCLNT option is set as 
REQDADM – All client applications using a privileged user ID (such as mqm) must provide a user ID and password in the MQCSP structure. Any applications using a non-privileged user ID are not required to provide a user ID and password and are treated as with the OPTIONAL setting.

i think this will work in my case ,am i correct ..any comments please?